# Finding the standard matrix of the transformation, is it unique?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have a question that asks:

For the linear transformation given, find the standard matrix of the transformation:

$T: R^2 \rightarrow R^2 $, such that $T$ reflects a vector about the line $y = -x$.

What I did was take the vectors

\begin{bmatrix}
      0 \\
      1 
\end{bmatrix} and \begin{bmatrix}
      1 \\
      0 
\end{bmatrix}

and drew the corresponding images and performed the transformation and got the matrix 
\begin{bmatrix}
      0 & -1 \\
      1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

However, the answer given is 
\begin{bmatrix}
      0 & -1 \\
      -1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

This lead me to wonder, is the standard matrix of the transformation not unique, or is my attempt at solving this completely wrong? Clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The transformation depends on a choice of basis.

Comment: It is unique, and the answer given is correct. By graphing this transformation, it should be clear that $(1, 0) \mapsto (0, -1)$ and $(0, 1) \mapsto (-1, 0)$. What you have produced is a rotation, counter-clockwise, by $\pi/2$ radians.

Comment: A reflection should have a determinant of -1. So, the first answer can't possibly be correct, in any basis.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct answer $$\begin{bmatrix}
      0 & -1 \\
      -1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

The first column is the reflection of $(1,0)$ and the second column is the reflection of $(0,1)$.